# MVC3 - Compress model in viewbag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, http-compression

I have an MVC3 view that's design to run reports for our clients.  In the View that lets you select the report options, I pass a large list of our clients (~3K).  I'm rendering it like this:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_ClientSelector", ViewBag.Clients as IEnumerable<Client>);}
```

The _ClientSelector partial looks like this:

```
<select id="clients" class="clientList" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach (Client client in Model) {
        var prefix = client.Parent == null ? "" : String.Format("{0}-({1}) / ", client.Parent.Name, client.Parent.Id);
            <option value="@client.Id">@prefix@client.Name-(@client.Id)</option>
    }
</select>
```

I'm using the jQuery multiselect library to turn this into a nice visual display.

My question is, is it possible to compress this list server side? By far, the slowest part of this view is loading this list of clients.  Using PageSpeed in chrome, it suggests compressing the html to make it load faster, is that possible?  If this needs to be in it's own controller action instead of putting it in the ViewBag, I don't mind doing that.  I just want to see if there is a way I can speed this page up.

Edit:

I started playing around with the templates you have below.  When I build json manually, it works.  However when I try to get it from the server using $.getJSON, it never fires on the results.  Using debug tools in Chrome, I see the response coming back, and it looks like valid json.   Can you spot something wrong with this?

```
public ActionResult ClientList() {
    var clients = reportRepository.GetClientList();
    IList<object> model = new List<object>();
    foreach (Phoenix.Models.Client c in clients) {
        var prefix = c.Parent == null ? "" : String.Format("{0}-({1}) / ", c.Parent.Name, c.Parent.Id);
        model.Add(new { value = c.Id.ToString(), text = String.Format("{0}{1}-({2})",prefix,c.Name,c.Id) });
    }
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Report/ClientList", null, function (data) {
            $("#templateOptionItem").tmpl(data).appendTo("#clients");
        });
    });
</script>
<script id="templateOptionItem" type="test/html">
    <option value=\'{{= value}}\'>{{= text}}</option>
</script>
<select id="clients" class="clientList" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

--This was another attempt using the $.ajax method, but it too does not fire on the results

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Report/ClientList",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#templateOptionItem").tmpl(data).appendTo("#clients");
    }
});
```

This is the example that works:

```
var Clients = [{ value: 1, text: "test123" },
               { value: 2, text: "123test" }]
$("#templateOptionItem").tmpl(Clients).appendTo("#clients");
```

After much tweaking, I finally got something to work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Report/ClientList",
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function (data) {
       $("#templateOptionItem").tmpl(JSON.parse(data.responseText)).appendTo("#clients");
    }
});
```

I'm still not sure why it would not fire on the on the success event, but using the complete event and doing a JSON.parse on the responseText seems to have done the trick.

Comment: By compressing html it probably means dynamic html compression performed by webserver, not your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought of sending it down to the view as JSON data and binding it to a [template in the client side](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/07/jquery-templates-and-data-linking-and-microsoft-contributing-to-jquery.aspx) or using a library like [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com).

The size of the data you are sending is increased largely because you are repeating the same html which you are generating for each of the 3k clients.  If you send that down with out mark up the size will be much smaller, and then the code for your list item can be sent down only once with place holders for json data.

EDIT: **This example is based on the idea that you are using knockout.**

JSON: Mind you if you are using knockout, this object would be annotated with ko.observable functions, or the use of the knockout.mapping.js could be used to auto apply the values across the entire onject

```
var JsonData = [ 
        { clientID : 'IDValye', Prefix : 'Some value for the prefix', Name = 'name value' } , 
        { ... } 
];
```

HTML:

```
<select id="clients" class="clientList" multiple="multiple" data-bind="template :{ name : 'optionTemplate', foreach : JsonData }">
</select>

<script type="text/html" id="optionTemplate">
    <option value="${ clientID }">${ Prefix }${ Name }-(${ clientID })</option>
</script>
```

You can get the rest of the detail on implementation of knockout from the tutorials on their site.

Comment: how would a template look for a select list like this?  The example on this page looks like a template for a single item, so the template is used for each item.

Comment: although knockout looks like a pretty great library, I'm already using jquery, jquery-ui and a few other jquery plugins.  I'd hate adding another large library to the project just for this one piece of functionality.  Thank you for the idea though, I will continue to play with transferring json and see if there's a way to do it with jquery.

Comment: Templating functionality has been added to jQuery 1.5 - see http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/ for details.

Comment: Yeah man using the jquery template engine as i pointed out in my first link.  Knockouts data-bind="template : {}" funcitonality is just and abstraction.  you could load all the data by simply applying the jQuery template as Scott Gu explains in the first link i added to this case.

Comment: Thanks for the help here, I think i've almost got it, but I'm having a hard time getting it to accept json coming from the server.  I updated my original post with the approach I'm taking, however it's not firing on the results from $.getJSON

Comment: Looks like you're getting this working without a framework, but since Knockout was mentioned I thought I'd throw out a name drop for Backbone, another template/data binding framework.  Backbone and its dependency underscore mesh quite well with jQuery.

Comment: @Brosto, just use the $.ajax({ contentTypeString : json }) 

Also, I would appreciate if you would accept the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: @Sergei - according to the documentation contentType is used when you're sending data to the server, dataType is what you're expecting back.  Anyhow, I'm having the same issue with $.ajax({...})  It's not firing on the return value.  I'll update my original post with the method I used.  As for accepting the answer, I've given you +1 for a helpful post, but my problem is not yet resolved, it's only opened up another problem with this ajax call.

Comment: Finally got something to work, I don't know if it's a very elegant solution, but none the less it works.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: success: function(data) {

$("#templateOptionItem").tmpl(data).appendTo("#clients");
    
}

Should work.

Comment: thats what I thought too, but you can see in my example above, i tried it but it would not fire on the success event.

Comment: can you post your response headers and message.  You should be able to pull it up from developer tools in chrome or firebug./